# Preparation for laminate floor went south

Tags: flooring, floor, laminate-floor

So I've setup few laminate floors so far, and I'm no expert at this but this is what I like to do in my spare time.

So I've got a condo in which there were carpets and I teared out those and all what comes with it. But I've uncovered something that I haven't seen before and so I don't know how to proceed. If found that the ending of the floor is not even as the rest of the floor, it's a bit lower. And this is where I wanted to put the reducer to finish off the laminate flooring.

Just for you to get an idea what I'm talking about here are some photos :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've put a wooden stick so you can spot how it lowers down. The floor ending is about 5-7 mm lower than the rest of the floor.

What do I do now?

Comment: When you say "floor ending", where exactly is this? Next to a vertical rising  wall, or next to something that drops, like a set of steps, or next to a different type of floor? I would think that with a 5-7mm drop, you can just shim the floor up (unless there are other problems with the spot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to fill the gap with a floor leveler.  You will clean area, prime it (primer is sold right next to floor leveler at big box), and add leveler.  You need a day for primer to dry usually and usually a day or two for leveler so add that into install timeline.